# How to access "The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.39 logs"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I am using windows 7 and have discovered that the log is available on a linux box but not a local instance of windows 7, so I cannot identify the error on my local machine, without access to the tomcat logs.  I have deployed to AWS but do not know how to access the logs on the linux box on AWS. I need to first identify the error before I can begin to search for a solution of that unknown error. [Here is the current URL of the deployed development test app](http://35.167.46.75/faces/index.xhtml).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  The problem was two-fold.  First Eclipse NEON has a bug that causes an AWT error, to resolve that error, you need to install WindowBuilder.  Second, I converted my Project to a Maven project and added the JSTL 1.2 dependency -- note, I had it already in the lib folder and added to the build path, but for whatever reason, the JSTL jar was not being found.  Now, the web application has no errors.

To access your AWS logs, they are located under the Beanstalk and on the left side the link is LOGS, click it and download.